# Application on GKE - some modification needed

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application deployed in GKE, where Infrastructure has been created using Terraform and deployment done in the below way using CICD pipeline via Jenkins :

GITHUB -> Docker image -> Google repository -> Kubernetes cluster.

Now, I have the below requirements, please provide your guidance on how should I approach :

1. The delivered infrastructure must be monitored and audited.
2. The delivered infrastructure must allow multiple personal accounts.
3. The pipeline must deploy the application across different environments on the target infrastructure.
4. The delivered infrastructure must be able to scale automatically.
5. How the service can be migrated to another region in case of any emergency?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to resolve issues

1. For auditing of logs and monitoring you can use the default GCP monitoring and logging, logging auto have the option to save the audit logs. GKE all operations will be audited there.
2. You can use GCP account with RBAC maybe
3. If you are using cloud build you can write YAML or JSON configuration that way to deploy across multiple environments or clusters but running specific trigger.
4. what do you mean by delivered? GKE support auto-scaling you can enable the cluster and node autoscaling to implement HPA & VPA.
5. Use regional cluster

Comment: Thanks Harsh for your response.

Comment: For the point 1, I am not sure what is the difference between using the default monitoring /logging  and third party tools like Datadog because I heard many projects use third party tools as well.

For 5, The requirement is to migrate in another region, So my understanding is that we need to use some tool in order to achieve that

Comment: For point 1. datadog is depends on requirement people mostly use open source grafana and Prometheus for monitoring also. for point 5 if you are using regional cluster no need to migrate anything LB only manage the traffic routing across region. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters

Comment: At the moment, we have the cluster in a single region, So that's why the concern has come that if there is any emergency and we need to move to another region, how that can be done.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-examples/tree/master/example-gke-k8s-multi-region